# How to use Matter.js on server with client-side renderer

Tags: javascript, websocket, matter.js

I'm writing a multiplayer game. Is there any fast ways to use MatterJS on the server (with `nodejs`, `ws`, `express`). My main problem is sending the world from server to client to renderer it on canvas. Because of the difficult world, is there any ways to use built-in `Matter.Engine` on frontend?
Could anyone help?

---

If this question is a bit not-detailed, please write questions in the comments.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61164289/running-matter-js-on-a-node-server)

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, for an authoritative server game, you'd want the engine to run server-side and the renderer to run client-side. Matter.js has separate objects for Engine and Render, which helps.

Here are a couple of approaches you could take:

1. Write your own renderer for the server side which sends updates down a websocket connection instead of rendering to the screen. Write your own engine object for the client side which receives websocket updates from the server to update object positions, angles, etc. to pass to the real renderer. Then, on the server you'd have the default Matter.js engine running but with your custom renderer, and on the client you'd have the default Matter.js renderer but with your custom engine. The Matter.js documentation would be a good start if you wish to take this approach.
2. Alternatively, run the default Engine on both the client and server, but on the client side, set objects as static. Do not set them as static on the server side. Then, the server can send updates down the socket that includes object ids, positions and angles. The client can then call code such as this to update the client-side engine:

```
Matter.Body.setPosition(body, update.position);
Matter.Body.setAngle(body, update.angle);
```

Approach #1 would take more effort to get working as you'd need to write a customer renderer and engine component, but approach #2 works reasonably well to get something started quickly. One thing to keep in mind is that in a multiplayer online game, latency becomes a challenge. Having the engine running on both the client and the server could be an advantage in that case, because you could in theory optimistically apply forces/positions client-side and then "tru-up" those updates once the server sends the next batch of updates.

Other than that, the architecture could look much like any other client/server game architecture.

Note that Matter.js can be installed with NPM in a Node environment--it doesn't have to run in a browser. You can easily wire that up with Express.js, ws or socket.io, and then start a loop where you call code such as this to periodically update the engine:

```
Matter.Engine.update(engine, 1000 / 60);
```

Hope that helps.